# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS reboots/crashes while running GPUs

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, overheating, cuda

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with CUDA 8.0, Tensorflow 1.1.0, and Keras 2.0.6. The system has two TitanX GPUs, which I'm using to train convolutional neural networks. I run these processes on Screen, and a single script usually takes about two days to complete. However, the system usually crashes and reboots during training, and I'm not sure why.

The logs I looked at indicate nothing about why the system reboots, and I checked to make sure none of the components were overheating.

Any ideas?

Comment: What temps are reported by the Nvidia-settings GPU temp selection, and what does the sensors command from the lm-sensors pacakge report?  Do you use a UPS, or monitor power in any way? Any particular time this happens (like in the morning when many other things get turned on)?

Comment: Right now I'm seeing 51°C and 65°C for the two GPUs. All of the CPU cores are between 40°C and 43°C. Those temps are pretty standard--I don't see them get much higher than that. I do use a UPS. It could be fairly consistently happening in the early morning around 05:00, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The last few times have been in the evening, actually. I don't think it's particularly a morning issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the issue by unplugging and reinstalling all the PSU cables in the system. Presumably one of them was loose and causing an anti-surge protection reboot. Apparently the motherboard displays this info to the screen when it happens, but I was always remotely connected to the server whenever it happened, so I couldn't see the message.